# Perl: Multiple global "or"-separated regex conditions in while block leads to an infinite loop?

Tags: regex, perl, loops, while-loop

I'm learning Perl and noticed a rather peculiar quirk -- attempting to match one of multiple regex conditions in a while loop results in that loop going on for infinity:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $hivar = "this or that";

while ($hivar =~ m/this/ig || $hivar =~ m/that/ig) {
        print "$&\n";
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
this
that
that
that
that
[...]
```

I'm wondering why this is? Are there any workarounds that are less clumsy than this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $hivar = "this or that";

while ($hivar =~ m/this|that/ig) {
        print "$&\n";
}
```

This is a simplification of a real-world problem I am encountering, and while I am interested in this in a practical standpoint, I also would like to know what behind-the-scenes is triggering this behavior. This is a question that doesn't seem to be very Google-compatible.

Thanks!

Tom

Comment: hobbes explained it quite well below, but so do Wall, Schwartz, et al.: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Global-matching

Comment: You might want to look here to see if the Regexp::Assemble package can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478083/how-can-i-efficiently-match-many-different-regex-patterns-in-perl

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The thing is that there's a hidden value associated *with each string*, not *with each match*, that controls where a `/g` match will attempt to continue, and accessible through `pos($string)`. What happens is:

1. `pos($hivar)` is 0, `/this/` matches at position 0 and resets `pos($hivar)` to 4. The second match isn't attempted because the or operator is already true. `$&` becomes "this" and gets printed.
2. `pos($hivar)` is 4, `/this/` fails to match because there's no "this" at position 4 or beyond. The failing match resets `pos($hivar)` to 0.
3. `/that/` matches at position 6 and resets `pos($hivar)` to 10. `$&` becomes "that" and gets printed.
4. `pos($hivar)` is 10, `/this/` fails to match because there's no "this" at position 10 or beyond. The failing match resets `pos($hivar)` to 0.
5. `/that/` matches at position 6 and resets `pos($hivar)` to 10. `$&` becomes "that" and gets printed.

and steps 4 and 5 repeat indefinitely.

Adding the `c` regex flag (which tells the engine not to reset `pos` on a failed match) solves the problem in the example code you provided, but it might or might not be the ideal solution to a more complex problem.

Comment: really well explainned, cookie for u.