# Multiple patterns with "|" ("or"): determine all matches?

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

I'm parsing logfiles and want to match a line against multiple patterns at once. I know I could benefit from [Regexp::Assemble](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regexp::Assemble) as proposed in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1478083/5830574). Unfortunately I cannot use it (because it would need deploying on dozens of production machines running Perl from 5.8.8 to 5.18.0 and both AIX and SLES11/12).

So I think I will have to stick with the `|`. I tried the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;
my @matches;

@matches = ( 'sjd one skj two sjf' =~ /(\bone\b)|(\btwo\b)|(\bthree\b)/ );
p @matches;
```

gives

> ```
> [
>     [0] "one",
>     [1] undef,
>     [2] undef
> ]
> ```

```
@matches = ( 'sjd onnne skj two sjf' =~ /(\bo.+e\b)|(\btwo\b)|(\bthree\b)/ );
p @matches;
```

gives

> ```
> [
>     [0] "onnne",
>     [1] undef,
>     [2] undef
> ]
> ```

```
@matches = ( 'sjd ONE skj two sjf' =~ /(\bone\b)|(\btwo\b)|(\bthree\b)/ );
p @matches;
```

gives

> ```
> [
>     [0] undef,
>     [1] "two",
>     [2] undef
> ]
> ```

```
@matches = ( 'sjd ONE skj TWO sjf' =~ /(\bone\b)|(\btwo\b)|(\bthree\b)/ );
p @matches;
```

gives

> ```
> []
> ```

From this I can tell whether there was a match or not. `@matches` is falsy for no match or contains the match at the corresponding position.
But in the first two cases there are actually *two* matches. Is there a way to make the code output both matches in the first case, like:

```
@matches = ( 'sjd one skj two sjf' =~ /(\bone\b)|(\btwo\b)|(\bthree\b)/ );
p @matches;
```

> ```
> [
>     [0] "one",
>     [1] "two",
>     [2] undef
> ]
> ```

I.e. so that `@matches` contains *all* matches, not just the first one?
Or do I have to loop through my patterns with an if/else cascade or something?

#### Update

Re-reading my question and your comments I realized that my question wasn't clear. Sorry for that.
Actually I *do* care which of the patterns matched and also the result of that match, i.e. for the line

```
$line = 'xxx two xxx one xxx';
```

and the patterns `/one/`, `/t.o/`, `/three/` I want to know that the pattern `/one/` matches `"one"` and the pattern `/t.o/` matches `"two"`. And that at best in one single step.

Comment: You don't need 5.10 to use Regexp::Assemble. In fact, Regexp::Assemble's main use and the one you are interested (optimizing alternations) became useless in 5.10 (since it became builtin).

Comment: @ikegami You are referring to the `~~` operator, right? Unfortunately my script must also run with 5.8.8 under AIX with _no_ extras installed. :-(

Comment: No, `~~` is experimental and likely to change. It should not be used. // R::A basically does `my $re = join '|', @regex_patterns;`, but optimizes the output in a way that's not needed in 5.10+ // That's not true. You installed a script. You can therefore install R::A.

Comment: I also found `~~` suspicious and am glad to hear that R::A seems superfluous for my case. // Technically true, but some "code from the internet" would have to be ack'ed by people from ITSec departments. It's not that easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following finds all the matches, but the output isn't what you requested:

```
my @matches = /\b(one|two|three)\b/g;
```

The following does exactly what you want:

```
my @matches;
($matches[0]) = /\b(one)\b/;
($matches[1]) = /\b(two)\b/;
($matches[2]) = /\b(three)\b/;
```

The following does it all in one match:

```
my @matches = /
   ^
   (?= .* /\b(one)\b )
   (?= .* /\b(two)\b )
       .* /\b(three)\b
/xs;
```

Comment: I would suggest that this best way if you don't care what match has triggered the capture. 

For example I want to capture a line in the log file if this pattern is matched.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I think I have to amend my question: actually I _do_ care which match triggered the capture because the line then need further processing (depending on which one matched).

Answer (score 1):

Do you care about the position of the match? If not, then you should use "non-capturing parenthes": `(?:..)` combined with a global match flag `/g`:

```
@matches = ( 'sjd one skj two sjf' =~ /(?:\bone\b)|(?:\btwo\b)|(?:\bthree\b)/g );
```

This produces:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'one',
          'two'
        ];
```